# SQL Query to update the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have a below tables

```
Table A
Col1  Col2        Col3
Ant   sugar,ice   2,3
Fly   sugar,ice   2,3
jack  water,dent  4,5
pack  water       4,5
hero  sugar,ice   2,3
```

i want to check the table data and 
have to update the table as

```
Col1  Col2        Col3
Ant   sugar,ice   2,3
Fly   Same as Ant 2,3
jack  water,dent  4,5
pack  water       4,5
hero  Same as Ant 2,3
```

help to solve the problem,
i had made the sample table to understand
thanks and regards.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: i am using SQL server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax may vary for different RDBMS, but since you have not specified one, the following query should be very close to "standard" SQL and should work on most engines:

```
UPDATE "Table A" AS A1
SET Col2 = 
(
    SELECT 'Same as ' + MIN(A2.Col1) 
    FROM "Table A" AS A2 
    WHERE A2.Col2 = A1.Col2 
    AND A2.Col1 < A1.Col1
)
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM "Table A" AS A2 
    WHERE A2.Col2 = A1.Col2 
    AND A2.Col1 < A1.Col1
)
```

Note: IMHO this is absolutely *horrid* design for a table schema and I think it is safe to say I would never use a table designed in such a manner. It may be worth you to read a good book on database design, especially the part about normalization.

Answer (score 0):

For `SQL Server`

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.col2 = CASE WHEN a.col1 = b.min_col1 
                    THEN a.col2
                    ELSE 'Same as ' + b.min_col1
                END
FROM    TableA a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  col2, MIN(col1) min_col1
            FROM    TableA
            GROUP   BY col2
        ) b ON a.col2 = b.col2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c14a/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════╦═════════════╦══════╗
║ COL1 ║    COL2     ║ COL3 ║
╠══════╬═════════════╬══════╣
║ Ant  ║ sugar,ice   ║ 2,3  ║
║ Fly  ║ Same as Ant ║ 2,3  ║
║ jack ║ water,dent  ║ 4,5  ║
║ pack ║ water       ║ 4,5  ║
║ hero ║ Same as Ant ║ 2,3  ║
╚══════╩═════════════╩══════╝
```